# Executable PyQt5 desktop apps

Tags: python, pyqt5, desktop-application

I am creating a desktop app with PyQt5 then making it executable with the pyinstaller, but I want to create an installation so that when I share just an exe file, people can first install dependencies, then run the app. Pyinstaller creates dist and builds folders on my PC, and I want this app to create these required folders on the other computer when exe file is used; what I want to do is make the app have a set-up so that all the dependencies will be installed for others. I searched on the internet but couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: [Bundling to One Folder](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#bundling-to-one-folder)?

Comment: Thanks, theoretically, that's what I want to have - just one exe file to share with the others. Still, the pyinstaller one folder option makes the app slower because each time app is run, it creates a temporary folder for the dependencies. What I exactly want is to distribute the exe file with an installer. In this case, just any other desktop apps, my app's dependencies will only be installed once when it runs for the first time with the help of the setup wizard

Comment: What kinds of libraries are included in the program? And are you using **CONDA** environment? It's true that using the OneFile option(-F) slows down your program, but it's not that slow unless you're using a large library. However, if you use the **CONDA** environment, the program may slow down because basically high-capacity mkl libraries are installed simultaneously when installing the numpy library.

Comment: I'm not really sure I'm understanding your query, specifically what you mean by "dependencies". If you're talking about python modules, there's little you can do: pyinstaller works by creating a temporary environment and eventually loads all required modules, and, AFAIK, those are loaded from the script directory (in One-Folder mode). The One-File option creates a full temporary directory with *all* contents. In both cases, you're using a separate python environment, there's no dynamic linking with possibly existing system libraries (except from those related to the system API).

Comment: So, the One-Folder option is theoretically better for performance (again, AFAIK), as it only creates the temporary python environment instead of uncompressing the whole archive every time the program is launched, and in that case what you need is an actual *installer* that properly *installs* the whole folder on the system (like InnoSetup or NullSoft's NSIS). Note that this will still install the required modules/path in the target folder, so they can only be used for your program. For instance, since you're referring to pyqt, this means that you're *not* installing PyQt (or Qt) in the system.

Comment: I am using Python virtual environment, in app, I want user to upload image, and I am sending image as a request and getting prediction from already deployed model, display. Basically, besides PyQt5, I am using NumPy and requests libraries. By dependencies, what I mean is, we have dist folder created by pyinstaller, and inside dist we have all required files (dependencies) for app to run. When we download any app from the internet, we see setup window at first run and it makes installation, that's what I want to have have for my app

Comment: You can make installers using inosetup. They have an installer wizard to help you through the process of creating an installer, but you can also write some scripts to create the installer from code.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxLdBDJjER4 Here's a tutorial on inosetup if you wanna see what it's like

Answer (score 1):

You can use pyinstaller with following command

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed myscript.py
```

this will create single exe file in dist folder
see this for more info
https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html#bundling-to-one-folder

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/packaging-pyqt5-pyside2-applications-windows-pyinstaller/), it uses InstallForge to create a setup for the app. If you have better options, it would be better to know